# header redirection after GET values

Tags: php, redirect

PROBLEM:
Header redirect was not functioning. See error message below.

Error message:
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/website/public_html/beta/popularity.php:3) in /home/website/public_html/beta/popularity.php on line 2

SOLUTION:
I pasted the entire code in question line by line into a new page...checking the header redirect was functioning each time. Everything works fine now.

Comment: You need to exit after the header call so it doesn't execute the rest of the script

Comment: Maybe the `include "includes/connect.php";` contains an echo in some place, that may cause a `Headers Already send problem`

Comment: What goes wrong? Do you get an error?

Comment: Maybe `connect.php` is dying with a fatal error or something?  Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: I'll wager that if you put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script you'll get an error that the headers can't be sent, and indicating that output had already started as of a line in `connect.php` or a subsequent include statement.

Comment: what do you need connect.php for anyway ?

Comment: Check for redundant spaces in the file, that could cause an issue.

Comment: I'd delete the trailing `?>` per page, they're little motherf*** that can inject whitespace